# Matlab : Save index in loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

Suppose I have

```
Data = 160 x 160 double
```

and I do this following :

```
    %1st loop
    for e=3:160
        D1(e)=Data(1,e);
    end
    %2nd loop
    for e=6:160
        for b=2:e-1
          D2(e)= min(Data(b,e)+D1(1,b-1));
        end
    end
```

The problem is, I want to save the `Data(b,e)` and `D1(1,b-1)` index which gives the minimum value for every `D2(e)` iteration. 
Is there any help? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your code correctly. To me it seems that at each loop iteration both `Data(b,e)` and `D1(1,b-1)` are scalar values of which you take the `min`. So `min(Data(b,e)+D1(1,b-1))` is equal to `Data(b,e)+D1(1,b-1)` (?) Or am I missing a range somewhere?

Comment: ie. for e = 6, I want to compare (Data(2,6)+D1(1)), (Data(3,6)+D1(2)), (Data(4,6)+D1(3)), and (Data(2,5)+D1(4)) so I can take the minimum value from those data (in scalar) and save it in D2 variable. Did I do something wrong? Let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? -

```
%1st loop
for e=3:8
    D1(e)=Data(1,e);
end
%2nd loop
for e=6:8
    var1 = NaN(e-2,1);
    for b=2:e-1
        var1(b-1) = Data(b,e)+D1(1,b-1);
    end
    [D2(e),Index(e)] = min(var1);
end

%%// Outputs - D2, Index
```